# UnMarshallException doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Tags: jaxb

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.example.abcd", ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());

if i run this, i am getting error that ""com.example.abcd" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index"

But this package has ObjectFactory class. I am just wondering why this is showing me the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the `ObjectFactory` class is annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.